# I need to implement a dispatch dictionary

Tags: python, dispatch

I need to implement a dispatch dictionary type and print it out
I currently have a printing problem **I need to print the David 1** entry but I get an exception
How I manage to print it
this func has the problem **printRecord()**

```
def make_medical_Record(name,num):
    medical_Record = {}

    def inData(act):
        if act in medical_Record:
            return True
        return False

    def addData(time,act):
        if act in medical_Record:
            medical_Record[act].append(time)
            medical_Record[act].sort()
        else:
            medical_Record[act] = [time]

    def view(value):
        print(medical_Record.get(value)) if medical_Record.get(value) else print("no events")
   
    def printRecord():
        def hasMore():
            return
        def next():
            return

        print(min(min(medical_Record,key=medical_Record.get())))
    
    instance = {'inData': inData,'notInData': notInData,'addData': addData,'view':view,'printRecord':printRecord }
    return instance

mr=make_medical_Record('David',1)
print(mr)
mr['addData']('15:00','hospital discharge')
pr=mr['printRecord']()
```

Comment: dispatch dictionary*

Comment: Including the exact exception (and stack trace) you're getting, and what sort of output you were hoping to get instead, would be helpful.

Comment: Just curious, is this from CS61A, or some other class using the Python port of SICP?  It looks a lot like the OOP module from SICP (where you build an OOP system out of Scheme lambdas), except in Python -- which is a little weird being as Python already has OOP built in,

Answer (score 0):

Your `printRecord` function doesn't look valid:

```
    def printRecord():
        def hasMore():
            return
        def next():
            return

        print(min(min(medical_Record,key=medical_Record.get())))
```

It's hard to tell from this code exactly what it's supposed to be doing, but you could use this as a starting point to just print all the data in the record object:

```
    def printRecord():
        print(name, num, medical_Record)
```